# Comparing url path in Django 2 middleware

Tags: python, django, url, middleware

I need to develop a Django middleware and created class like this:

```
import re
from django.conf import settings
from django.shortcuts import redirect
from django.contrib.auth import logout


class LoginRequiredMiddleware:

    def __init__(self, get_response):
        self.get_response = get_response

    def __call__(self, request):
        response = self.get_response(request)
        return response

    def process_view(self, request, view_func, view_args, view_kwargs):
        assert hasattr(request, 'user')

        path = request.path_info
        print(path)

        p = path.lstrip('/')
        compiled_login_url = re.compile(settings.LOGIN_URL)

        print(compiled_login_url.match(p))


        if not request.user.is_authenticated:
            if path == '/':
                print("==============> INDEX PAGE")
```

Now here, I want to compare the path of urls. I have to determine if path match with **settings.LOGIN_URL** or not. I have tried using regular expressions, but they did no help.

Here are my urls

```
urlpatterns = [
              path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
              path('', views.index, name='index'),
              path('<slug:slug>/', include('app.urls')),
              path('<slug:slug>/accounts/login/', views.login, name='login'),
              path('<slug:slug>/accounts/logout/', views.logout, name='logout'),
              path('<slug:slug>/dashboard/', 'views.dashboard', name='dashboard'),
          ] + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

I want to exempt **login** and **logout** from being checked in middleware also I need **slug**.

**views.py**

```
def user_login(request, slug):
    """
    Login user using email and password

    :param request: WSGI Request
    :param slug: to verify the facility
    :return: login page or redirect
    """

    context = {}
    try:
        facility = models.Facility.objects.get(slug=slug)
        context['facility'] = facility

    except models.Facility.DoesNotExist:
        return redirect('index')

    if request.method == "POST":
        email = request.POST['email']
        password = request.POST['password']

        user = authenticate(request, username=email, password=password)
        if user is not None:
            if user.profile.facility.slug == slug:
                login(request, user)
                return redirect('dashboard', slug=slug)
            else:
                context['error'] = "You don't belong to this facility"

        else:
            context['error'] = "Invalid email or password"

    return render(request, 'app/user/login.html', context)


@login_required
def dashboard(request, slug):
    """
    Display the dashboard of facility and list down bird
    view for the daily, weekly, monthly and yearly progress

    :param request:
    :return:
    """
    context = {}

    try:
        facility = models.Facility.objects.get(slug=slug)
        context['facility'] = facility
    except models.Facility.DoesNotExist:
        return render(request, 'app/404.html', status=404)
```

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>
<ul>
    {% for f in facilities %}
        <li><a href="{% url 'login' f.slug %}">{{ f.name }}</a></li>
    {% empty %}
        <li>No Facility</li>
    {% endfor %}
</ul>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can't you use `resolve()` to get the current view function and then `reverse(settings.LOGIN_URL)` and see if they're the same?

Comment: but problem is slug, how I can pass it to login url or compare url

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could add Django's auth views one by one to your `urlpatterns`, decorating each with `login_exempt`.

## **OR**

If you would like to move the checking into the middleware you could try something like:

**`urls.py`**

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', include("myapp.urls")),
    path('accounts/', include('django.contrib.auth.urls', namespace="accounts"))
]
```

**`middleware.py`**

```
class LoginRequiredMiddleware:            # <-- Custom Middleware
    def __init__(self, get_response):
        self.get_response = get_response

    def __call__(self, request):
        return self.get_response(request)

    def process_view(self, request, view_func, view_args, view_kwargs):

        if getattr(view_func, 'login_exempt', False):
            return

        if 'accounts' in request.resolver_match.namespaces:
            return
```

Other possibilities would maybe be checking the url or view name in the middleware, but still maybe the cleanest would be using your decorator and add the necessary views one by one.

## OR

You can use [django-decorator-include](https://pypi.org/project/django-decorator-include/) for this.

```
$ pip install django-decorator-include
```

In you `project/url.py`

```
from decorator_include import decorator_include
from project/custom_middleware import login_exempt


urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', include("myapp.urls")),
    # do this 
    path('accounts/', decorator_include(login_exempt, 'django.contrib.auth.urls'))


]
```

Don't forget to add the package in `requirements.txt`

Comment: I have also tried adding  **@login_required** decorator, but still the problem is, I can't send my **slug** parameter to it. I need auth urls to be like `slug/accounts/login`

Comment: @thezeeshantariq post your `views` and template code also.

Comment: nothing, it simply doesn't work. `re.comile` returns **None**